# iPhone Audio Modifications (filters/effects)

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, core-audio, openal

I am developing an app where the user can record their voice, and then alter it in some way. I have implemented OpenAL, and I am able to adjust the pitch to speed up and slow down the audio file. The thing is, I want to add filters like echo, reverb, etc.. I have scoured the internet for hours and have found nothing to help me. I came across a OpenAL called FreeSL, which has a bunch of filters built in, but I cannot get it compile in xcode.

I have also looked into Dirac3, but again all I am seeing is basic pitch/time controls; no echos or anything.

Can anyone point me in the direction a good framework or explain how OpenAL can handle filters like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a library that is exactly what I am looking for, FMOD:

http://www.fmod.org/index.php/fmod